# terraform - Unable to fetch service account from Kubernetes: serviceaccounts "<name of service account>" not found

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform

This was working perfectly fine before but for some reason it no longer is, would appreciate if someone can help fix this:

My terraform code as follows, have replaced key info. with "<>" just for sharing publicly here:

Outer main.tf has this:

```
    module "<name>_service_account" {
  source = "../modules/kubernetes/service-account"
  name   = "<name>-deployer"
}

# Create <name> platform namespace
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "<name>-platform" {
  metadata {
    name = "<name>-platform"
  }
}
```

The service account main.tf module:

```
resource "kubernetes_service_account" "serviceaccount" {
  metadata {
    name      = var.name
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }
}


resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "serviceaccount" {
  metadata {
    name = var.name
  }

  subject {
    kind = "User"
    name = "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:${var.name}"
  }

  role_ref {
    kind      = "ClusterRole"
    name      = "cluster-admin"
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  }
}

data "kubernetes_service_account" "serviceaccount" {
  metadata {
    name = var.name
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }
  depends_on = [
    resource.kubernetes_service_account.serviceaccount
  ]
}

data "kubernetes_secret" "serviceaccount" {
  metadata {
    name = data.kubernetes_service_account.serviceaccount.default_secret_name
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }
  binary_data = {
    "token": ""
  }
  depends_on = [
    resource.kubernetes_service_account.serviceaccount
  ]
}
```

My outputs.tf for the above module:

```
output "secret_token" {
    sensitive = true
    value = lookup(data.kubernetes_secret.serviceaccount.binary_data, "token")
}
```

The error that I get in my terraform pipeline:

```
│ Error: Unable to fetch service account from Kubernetes: serviceaccounts "<name>-deployer" not found
│ 
│   with module.<name>_service_account.data.kubernetes_service_account.serviceaccount,
│   on ../modules/kubernetes/service-account/main.tf line 27, in data "kubernetes_service_account" "serviceaccount":
│   27: data "kubernetes_service_account" "serviceaccount" {
```

Comment: Has the `var.name` value changed?

Comment: exact same name, it is in the outer main.tf where it calls the module

Comment: Can you run `kubectl` to check if the ServiceAccount still exists?

Comment: Figured it out, this is a new environment/project and I had the terraform refresh stage still in the pipeline hence why it couldnt find the service account, removing that and just letting the plan and apply run first solved it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, this is a new environment/project and I had the terraform refresh stage still in the pipeline hence why it couldnt find the service account, removing that and just letting the plan and apply run first solved it.